# Generate SOAP XML using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, soap

Has anyone generated XML files using SQL Server in a SOAP format? I am trying to generate the following structure from SQL, but I cannot figure it out if the `FOR XML` clause is the best approach for this. Can anyone give some suggestions? Maybe another approach for this kind of files? Thanks

**SOAP XML structure**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns=""></To>
      <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns=""></Action>
   </s:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:StoreDocument xmlns:tns="">
         <tns:StoreDocumentMessage>
            <q1:SystemCode xmlns:q1=""></q1:SystemCode>
            <q1:TransmissionUID xmlns:q1="">d2032705-5478-4694-98f9-d2eafa3933b2</q1:TransmissionUID>
            <q1:DocumentSection xmlns:q1="">
               <q17:DocumentType xmlns:q17="">1</q17:DocumentType>
               <q17:DocumentNumber xmlns:q17="">0000006965</q17:DocumentNumber>
               <q17:DocumentUID xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="" xmlns:xsi=""/>
               <q17:CreationDateTimeUTC xmlns:q17="">2017-08-04 09:09:29 -03:00</q17:CreationDateTimeUTC>
               <q17:DocumentStatus xmlns:q17="">2</q17:DocumentStatus>
               <q17:LatestGoodIssueDate xmlns:q17="">2017-08-04 13:35:16 -03:00</q17:LatestGoodIssueDate>
               <q17:Reference xmlns:q17="">0000013254</q17:Reference>
               <q17:TotalOrderedProducts xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="" xmlns:xsi=""/>
               <q17:OrderedProducts xmlns:q17="">
                  <q17:OrderedProductSection>
                     <q17:ProductCode>2152157</q17:ProductCode>
                     <q17:OrderedQuantity>500000</q17:OrderedQuantity>
               </q17:OrderedProducts>
               <q17:RelatedDocumentSection xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="" xmlns:xsi=""/>
               <q17:StockOwnerSection xmlns:q17="">
                  <q17:StockOwnerCode></q17:StockOwnerCode>
                  <q17:StockOwnerName></q17:StockOwnerName>
                  <q17:StockOwnerAddress1></q17:StockOwnerAddress1>
                  <q17:StockOwnerAddress2/>
                  <q17:StockOwnerZIP>1407</q17:StockOwnerZIP>
                  <q17:StockOwnerCity></q17:StockOwnerCity>
                  <q17:StockOwnerNameRomanized></q17:StockOwnerNameRomanized>
                  <q17:StockOwnerAddress1Romanized></q17:StockOwnerAddress1Romanized>
                  <q17:StockOwnerAddress2Romanized/>
                  <q17:StockOwnerZIPRomanized></q17:StockOwnerZIPRomanized>
                  <q17:StockOwnerCityRomanized></q17:StockOwnerCityRomanized>
                  <q17:StockOwnerCountry></q17:StockOwnerCountry>
                  <q17:StockOwnerGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi=""/>
               </q17:StockOwnerSection>
         </tns:StoreDocumentMessage>
      </tns:StoreDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I managed to do the following stored procedure. Hope will help!

```
DECLARE @XMLFINAL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMLFINAL=''
DECLARE @nr NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Records CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT TOP 10 GID FROM ESFITradeAccount

OPEN Records
FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @nr
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @XML=''  
SET @XML=(
SELECT  (

SELECT 
Code, Name

FROM ESFITradeAccount WHERE GID=@nr
FOR
XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
))

FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @nr

SET @XMLFINAL=@XMLFINAL+@XML
END

CLOSE Records DEALLOCATE Records


IF @XMLFINAL IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN    
INSERT INTO EXPORTAEVWMS_Test (XML, Send)
SELECT @XMLFINAL,'0'

DECLARE @XMLEXPOPRT VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMLEXPOPRT='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
+'<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
+'<To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://10.2.3.92:8201/FlexibleStorage/Transmission?wsdl</To>'
+'<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Interfaces/TransmissionServer/StoreDocument</Action>'
+'</s:Header>'
+'<soapenv:Body>'
+'<tns:StoreDocument xmlns:tns="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Interfaces">'
+'<tns:StoreDocumentMessage>'
+'<q1:SystemCode xmlns:q1="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Messages">ROM_ENTSOFT_PROD</q1:SystemCode>' -- system code
+'<q1:TransmissionUID xmlns:q1="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Messages">'+convert(nvarchar(36), newid())+'</q1:TransmissionUID>' -- generated GID
+'<q1:DocumentSection xmlns:q1="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Messages">' 
+'<q17:DocumentType xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">1</q17:DocumentType>' -- fix value (1) 
+'<q17:DocumentNumber xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">0000006965</q17:DocumentNumber>' -- ADCode of delivery note
+'<q17:DocumentUID xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- not used
+'<q17:CreationDateTimeUTC xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'+format((SELECT ESDCreated FROM PurchasesDocuments), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')+'</q17:CreationDateTimeUTC>' -- timestamp of the order
+'<q17:DocumentStatus xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">2</q17:DocumentStatus>' -- 1 = Open; 2 = Shipped;
+'<q17:LatestGoodIssueDate xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'+format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')+'</q17:LatestGoodIssueDate>' -- the date when the goods are shipped
+'<q17:Reference xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">0000013254</q17:Reference>' -- invoice number
+'<q17:TotalOrderedProducts xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- not used
+'<q17:OrderedProducts xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">' -- document lines (RSKU + Quantity)
+@XMLFINAL
+'</q17:OrderedProducts>'
+'<q17:RelatedDocumentSection xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- left empty (not used)
+'<q17:StockOwnerSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">' -- the section related to StocOwnerSection contain the address of the market headquarter (ITDR Romania)
+'<q17:StockOwnerCode>E172</q17:StockOwnerCode>' -- ITDR headquarter
+'<q17:StockOwnerName>Импириъл Табако Дистрибуция ЕООД</q17:StockOwnerName>' -- company name
+'<q17:StockOwnerAddress1>ул. Хенрих Ибсен 15, ет.4, офис 4</q17:StockOwnerAddress1>' -- company address1
+'<q17:StockOwnerAddress2/>' -- company address2
+'<q17:StockOwnerZIP>1407</q17:StockOwnerZIP>' -- company ZIP code
+'<q17:StockOwnerCity>София</q17:StockOwnerCity>' -- company city
+'<q17:StockOwnerNameRomanized>Imperial Tobacco Distribution</q17:StockOwnerNameRomanized>' -- romanian info (company name)
+'<q17:StockOwnerAddress1Romanized>str. Heinrich Ibsen 15 et.4</q17:StockOwnerAddress1Romanized>' -- romanian info (company address1)
+'<q17:StockOwnerAddress2Romanized/>' -- romanian info (company address2)
+'<q17:StockOwnerZIPRomanized>1407</q17:StockOwnerZIPRomanized>' -- romanian info (company ZIP code)
+'<q17:StockOwnerCityRomanized>SOFIA</q17:StockOwnerCityRomanized>' -- country description of the owner
+'<q17:StockOwnerCountry>BG</q17:StockOwnerCountry>' -- country code of the owner 
+'<q17:StockOwnerGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- left empty (not used)
+'</q17:StockOwnerSection>'
+'<q17:DestinationSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'
+'<q17:DestinationCode>13400001</q17:DestinationCode>'
+'<q17:DestinationName>Табако Трейд ООД</q17:DestinationName>'
+'<q17:DestinationAddress1>Пловдив бул. Христо Ботев 94</q17:DestinationAddress1>'
+'<q17:DestinationAddress2 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:DestinationZIP>4000</q17:DestinationZIP>'
+'<q17:DestinationCity>Пловдив</q17:DestinationCity>'
+'<q17:DestinationNameRomanized>Tobacco Trade LTD</q17:DestinationNameRomanized>'
+'<q17:DestinationAddress1Romanized>137 Bresovsko shose Str.</q17:DestinationAddress1Romanized>'
+'<q17:DestinationAddress2Romanized xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:DestinationZIPRomanized>4000</q17:DestinationZIPRomanized>'
+'<q17:DestinationCityRomanized>Plovdiv</q17:DestinationCityRomanized>'
+'<q17:DestinationCountry>BG</q17:DestinationCountry>'
+'<q17:DestinationGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:DestinationCoord xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'</q17:DestinationSection>'
+'<q17:SoldToSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'
+'<q17:SoldToCode>13400001</q17:SoldToCode>'
+'<q17:SoldToName>Табако Трейд ООД</q17:SoldToName>'
+'<q17:SoldToAddress1>Пловдив бул. Христо Ботев 94</q17:SoldToAddress1>'
+'<q17:SoldToAddress2 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:SoldToZIP>4000</q17:SoldToZIP>'
+'<q17:SoldToCity>Пловдив</q17:SoldToCity>'
+'<q17:SoldToNameRomanized>Tobacco Trade LTD</q17:SoldToNameRomanized>'
+'<q17:SoldToAddress1Romanized>137 Bresovsko shose Str.</q17:SoldToAddress1Romanized>'
+'<q17:SoldToAddress2Romanized xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:SoldToZIPRomanized>4000</q17:SoldToZIPRomanized>'
+'<q17:SoldToCityRomanized>Plovdiv</q17:SoldToCityRomanized>'
+'<q17:SoldToCountry>BG</q17:SoldToCountry>'
+'<q17:SoldToGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:SoldToSameGroupAsStockOwner>false</q17:SoldToSameGroupAsStockOwner>'
+'</q17:SoldToSection>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationCode>BG9992</q17:TrackingLocationCode>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationName>Импириъл Табако Дистрибуция ЕООД</q17:TrackingLocationName>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress1>Ул. Иван Георгов 3</q17:TrackingLocationAddress1>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress2>Военна рампа</q17:TrackingLocationAddress2>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationZIP>1220</q17:TrackingLocationZIP>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationCity>София</q17:TrackingLocationCity>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationNameRomanized>Imperial Tobacco Distribution</q17:TrackingLocationNameRomanized>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress1Romanized>3 Ivan Georgov Str.</q17:TrackingLocationAddress1Romanized>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress2Romanized>Voenna rampa</q17:TrackingLocationAddress2Romanized>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationZIPRomanized>1220</q17:TrackingLocationZIPRomanized>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationCityRomanized>SOFIA</q17:TrackingLocationCityRomanized>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationCountry>BG</q17:TrackingLocationCountry>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'<q17:TrackingLocationCoord xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
+'</q17:TrackingLocationSection>'
+'</q1:DocumentSection>'
+'</tns:StoreDocumentMessage>'
+'</tns:StoreDocument>'
+'</soapenv:Body>'
+'</soapenv:Envelope>'

DECLARE @name varchar(250);
SET @name='StoreDocument'+'.xml'

EXEC ExportXML @XMLEXPOPRT,'D:\TT',@name;
END

GO
```

Comment: To use / preserve the namespace for the elements generated with the "FOR XML" clause, use "FOR XML RAW" ( see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces ) with or without the WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns1) clause...